# Reduce CSS Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Is there a way to make the following CSS code more compact and clean?**

```
.offset-0 p.artist   {  padding-top: 165px; }   
.offset-25 img {    margin-top: -25px;      }
.offset-25 p.artist   { padding-top: 140px; }   
.offset-50 img {    margin-top: -50px;      }
.offset-50 p.artist   { padding-top: 115px; }   
.offset-75 img {    margin-top: -75px;      }
.offset-75 p.artist   { padding-top: 90px;  }   
.offset-100 img {   margin-top: -100px;     }
.offset-100 p.artist   {    padding-top: 65px;  }   
.offset-125 img {   margin-top: -125px;     }
.offset-125 p.artist   {    padding-top: 40px;  }   
.offset-150 img {   margin-top: -150px;     }
.offset-150 p.artist   {    padding-top: 15px;  }   
.offset-175 img {   margin-top: -175px;     }
.offset-175 p.artist   {    padding-top: -10px; }   
.offset-200 img {   margin-top: -200px;     }
.offset-200 p.artist   {    padding-top: -35px; }
```

Comment: That already looks pretty compact to me. What makes you want to make this more compact?

Comment: @Craigy Craigo  minify it https://cssminifier.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make that CSS more compact using pure CSS. However, you can use a framework/plugin such as [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com) or [Less](http://lesscss.org) to do so. Frameworks/plugins are the only options, as the CSS you have currently giving different values to different elements within elements with different classes.

Comment: Yes you can by using CSSVariables and removing negative paddings (no such thing)

Comment: SASS/SCSS/Less would compile the same CSS though.

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS Variables**

```
.offset-0   { --pt: 165px;               }
.offset-25  { --pt: 140px; --mt: -25px;  }
.offset-50  { --pt: 115px; --mt: -50px;  }
.offset-75  { --pt:  90px; --mt: -75px;  }
.offset-100 { --pt:  65px; --mt: -100px; }
.offset-125 { --pt:  40px; --mt: -125px; }
.offset-150 { --pt:  15px; --mt: -150px; }
.offset-175 {              --mt: -175px; }
.offset-200 {              --mt: -200px; }

[class|="offset"] p.artist { padding-top: var(--pt); }
[class|="offset"] img { margin-top: var(--mt); }
```